# Can we have more than 1 condition in Exclusion script for triggered sends in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, exclusion-script

I have setup a triggered send in marketing cloud and it has the following sendable DE.(example:)

| Email_address | product_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test@gmail.com | 3700 | xxx |

I wish to add an exclusion script to this triggered send and i know that we can use the below ampScript to exclude emails.

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Suppression", "Email Address", emailaddr))> 0
```

I have a few questions on this,

1. Can I change "emailaddr" in the above code to "Email_address"(name of the sendable DE used in my triggered send) and the codee still works??
2. Is it possible to use additional condition in the exclusion script,
   example :

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Suppression", "Email Address", emailaddr,"Prod_id",product_id))> 0
```

Please, could anyone let me know?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I change "emailaddr" in the above code to "Email_address"(name of
> the sendable DE used in my triggered send) and the code still works??

"Suppression" is the name of the Data Extension, so make sure you change the right attribute in the LOOKUPROWS function. This means you should change "Email Address" to "Email_address" and "Suppression" to the name of your Suppression Data Extension.

> Is it possible to use additional condition in the exclusion script

Yes, but make sure you know what you're doing -  do you have a `product_id` field in your sendable Data Extension? `Prod_id` is not the name of the field in your Supression DE - it should be `product_id`. Here's how it could be done if you have all the correct data in data extensions:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Name of you Suppression DE", "Email_Address", emailaddr,"product_id", product_id))> 0
```

I suggest you learn more about the [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) function to make sure you are using the right arguments in the right places.

Comment: @bitsy - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!